# Oracle Apex Turn JS - JavaScript files incorporation

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

How can I implement this JS file:

http://www.turnjs.com/

Into my apex page?
I've addded the .js file into the App static files and this to the page HTML Header:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="turn.min.js"></script>
<script> $('#album').turn({gradients: true, acceleration: true}); </script>
```

This to the Javascript Files URL:

```
#APP_FILES#turn.min.js
```

And a static region with the following:

```
<div id="album">
        <div style="background-image: url(#APP_FILES#image1.JPG);">a</div>
        <div style="background-image: url(#APP_FILES#image2.png);">b</div>
        <div style="background-image: url(#APP_FILES#image3.JPG);">c</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work.
Anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you may be experiencing a JS complaint on your page. Have you checked the browser console for errors? The src=turn is duplicating what the JS URL does, and may be the source of the complaint, since it won't know where that file is. The $('#album').turn call can be moved to the 'Execute on page load' section. And the jquery.js can possibly be ommitted, or join the list in the JS URL attribute.